# Lucene- Extracting sentence in which word match occurs

Tags: lucene

I'm a newbie to Lucene. In the course of understanding it, I could successfully index the files in a directory and I did a basic lucene search to get the list of files in which a particular word is present.

Now I'm trying to extract the sentence from a file in which the search word is present. 
I've searched a lot but couldn't figure out.

Regards.

Comment: Check out Lucene's [Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html).

Comment: Lucene's Highlighter doesn't help when you want to extract sentences.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  I don't think it was clear to either AR1 or myself what you meant.  Usually when people ask to extract the matching sentence they mean "like what google does", which is to say, not really sentences at all, but text fragments.  That aside, sounds like you've solved your problem now, in which case you are always encouraged to go ahead and [answer it yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your response.

I was trying to extract index of sentences in the directory of files but not the "relavent/best text/fragment".

Here is how I solved the problem:
    Using **"two-level indexing"** --> first index the files in a directory & then index sentences in each file. This made my job pretty easier & faster.

Anyways, thanks again for the help :)

Comment: Does this mean that you could also do a sentence level search to return all documents that contain your query in the same sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the method

org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter.getBestFragment

Such method gets in input the set of tokens generated analyzing the original text, and returns in output the most relevant text fragments. Please remember to trim the fragments if they are too big.